# Proper use of a DI container

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

This is my first time creating a Node.js backend before I used ASP.NET Core. I would like to use some kind of DI Container and use controllers with it. In ASP.NET Core, an instance of the controller class is created for each request, and I don’t understand if this is required in Node.js or if controllers are better done in the form of singletons that will be located in the DI Container.

```
export class TestController extends ControllerBase {
  construct() {
    router.get("/test", function (req, res) {
      res.send("Test");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thinking in terms of "controllers" may be missing the forest for the trees. Or missing the point by focusing on the wrong abstraction. In JS you are free to use functions and that's how *endpoints* are registered - for each route, you register a function to handle it. While a *controller* will be bundling more than one endpoint and, in general, work on a more macro scale than each function. Which gives you *more* freedom to have each request be handled by separate executions. Receiving three requests thus runs three functions, rather than create three objects with their inheritance.

Comment: @VLAZ Do you mean that it's better to use functions and modules instead of controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inversify-express-utils](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-express-utils) package and its [BaseHttpController](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-express-utils#basehttpcontroller). Your example could be:

```
import { injectable, inject } from "inversify";
import {
    controller, httpGet, BaseHttpController, HttpResponseMessage, StringContent
} from "inversify-express-utils";

@controller("/")
class ExampleController extends BaseHttpController {
    @httpGet("/test")
    public async get() {
        const response = new HttpResponseMessage(200);
        response.content = 'test';
        return response;
    }
```

[InversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS#installation) is an IoC for TypeScript and JavaScript apps